# Why is the Primary Key often an integer in a Relational Database Management System?

Tags: sql, database-design

It's been habitual in most of the scenarios while developing a database design we set primary key as integer type for a unique identifier in the Table. Why not use string or float for primary keys? Does this affect the accessibility of values, or in plain words *retrieval speed*? Are there any specific reasons?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An integer will use less disk space than a string, thus giving you a smaller index file to search through. This is important for large tables where you want to have as much of the index as possible cached in RAM.

Also, they can be autoincremented so you don't need to write your own routines to generate keys.

You often want to have a technical key (also called a *surrogate key*), a key that is only used to identify the row and not used for anything else. Most data may change sooner or later for reasons you can't control and you don't want to update it everywhere. Even such seemingly static data as a nation-assigned personal id number can change (if you get a new identity) or there may be laws prohibiting their use. A key generated by you, however, is in your own control. For such surrogate keys it's useful to have a *small key* that is *easily generated*.

As for "floats as primary keys": Don't do this. A primary key should uniquely identify a row. Floats have no equality relation, which means you cannot safely compare two float values for equality. This is an inherent shortcoming of floating-point values. If you need decimals, use a fixed-point number type instead.

Comment: This "technical key" is also known as *surrogate key*. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key

Comment: Actually, I don't think surrogate (or "technical") keys really have much to do with normalization.

Answer (score 2):

The primary key is supposed to be an index that can provide a unique way to access a specific row in a table.  Primary keys can be most data types (in practical applications, float/double won't work too well), and primary keys can also be compound keys (comprised of several columns.)

If you carefully examine the data in the table, you might be able to find a data item that will be unique for every row in the table, thereby eliminating the requirement that you fabricate a key like the autoincrement integer that you find in some schemas.

If you're in a manufacturing environment it might be an alphanumeric field like part number or assembly identifier.  Retail or warehousing applications might have a stock number or combination of stock number/shipment/manufacturer.

Generally, If some data in your table is supposed to be a unique identifier it probably will serve well as a primary key for your table.

Using data that exists in the table already completely eliminates the requirement to "make up" a value (such as the autoincrement column) and use it as the primary key.  This saves space since it's one less column in the table and one less index on the table.

Yes, in my experience integer keys are almost always faster, since it's more efficient for the database engine to compare integers than comparing strings.  Depending on the "uniqueness" of the data (technically called cardinality http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_(SQL_statements)), the effect of character vs. integer keys is nominal.

Character keys may degrade performance depending on the number of characters that the database needs to compare to determine whether keys are equal or not equal.  In the pathological case, imagine a hundred-character field which differ only on the right hand side.  One row has 100 A's.  We need to compare this to a key with 99 A's and a B as the last character.  Conceptually, databases compare character fields just like `strcmp()` (`strncmp()` if you prefer) from left to right.

good luck!

Comment: Ahhh, ignore this answer and look at the best answer. The last two paragraphs are just wrong.

Comment: Hey your link could use an extra ')' at the end to point to the correct URL. I'm not allowed to update that because it's fewer than six characters.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason is for performance.

A logical database design should specify which "real" columns are unique, but when the logical design is transformed into a physical design, it is traditional to not use any of these "natural" keys as the primary key; instead, a meaningless integer column is added for this purpose - called a "surrogate key".

Normally the designer will add further unique constraints for the "real" uniqueness business rules as specified in the logical design.

This is because most DBMS's have trouble updating a primary key (e.g. due to performance issues when cascading the update to child tables). Some DBMS's might not be able to support non-integer primary keys at all.

Some side notes:

- There's no theoretical reason why
  primary keys should be immutable.
- This is nothing to do with
  normalization, which happens in the
  logical model (which should never
  have surrogate keys).
- Also, note that the idea of a
  "primary" key is not a relational
  concept - it is simply a way of
  denoting the "preferred" uniqueness
  constraint, perhaps for relational
  integrity - but there's nothing in
  the RM that says that you must use
  the same key for each child table.
- I've created natural keys as "Primary
  Keys" in Oracle databases before,
  albeit rarely. I've even had them
  used for foreign key constraints.
  Admittedly, they were either
  immutable, or I hand-wrote the
  update-cascade code; and I had
  trouble with one front-end
  application where the PK included a
  date column.

Bottom line: there is no theoretical requirement for surrogate keys, but they're much more practical than the alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that it is because we can auto-increment integer values so it's easy to generate a new unique key for every insert.

Answer (score 1):

Many common ORM ([Object Relational Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)) tools either force to use or at least recommend using integer as primary key.

Integer primary key also saves space compared to string and integer primary key is in some cases also faster. Sequences or auto increment fields make integer primary key generation easy at least if you do not work with distributed databases.

Answer (score 1):

These are some of the main reasons why i think we have integers/ numbers as primary keys.

1.Primary keys should be able to uniquely define your row and should be immutable. One of the problems with using real attributes (name etc..) is that they could change over time. To maintain relational integrity in such a case would be very difficult as this change needs to cascade to all the child records.

2.The size of the table and thereby the index would be smaller in case we use a number as a key for the tab.e

3.Since these are automatically generated using a sequence, we can be sure that the values would be unique under all circumstances.

Check this.
http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=3916511&#3916511